# How to create Java ANTLR parser for Swift language?

Tags: java, swift, antlr

I'm trying to make AST of Swift sources in Java. I also use Windows

What I did:

1. Downloaded `antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar`
2. Added it to classpath
3. Created files `grun.bat` and `antlr4.bat`, added them to PATH
4. Downloaded https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift3/Swift3.g4
5. Ran `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Java Swift3.g4`
6. Parser created a few files (including Java sources)
7. I built `antlr4-runtime-4.7.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` using those instructions https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/building-antlr.md

But now I don't understand what should I do with https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift3/src/main/java/SwiftSupport.java which is also a part of Swift grammar. What should I do with generated files? Simply add them to my sources, define `package` and job is done? I also see that ANTLR generates only tokens, will I have to build AST by myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did everything good, now I can parse Swift files with code

```
Swift3Lexer swiftLexer = new Swift3Lexer(CharStreams.fromFileName(file.getAbsolutePath()));
CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(swiftLexer);
Swift3Parser swiftParser = new Swift3Parser(commonTokenStream);

Top_levelContext topLevel = swiftParser.top_level(); // it works
```